# How to check if the multipart upload was successful with alamofire image

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, alamofire, promisekit

I am making a network call to upload an image to a backend server. Right now I am using the following to code. This code works perfectly in conditions where the internet is online.

```
// MARK: - PUT

    static func PUT(URL: String,
                    data: Data,
                    mimeType: String,
                    headers: [String: String]?) -> Promise<Void>
    {
        return Promise { fulfill, reject in

            let URL = try! URLRequest(url: URL, method: .put, headers: headers)

            Alamofire.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                    multipartFormData.append(InputStream.init(data: data), withLength: UInt64(data.count), name: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: mimeType)
            },
            with: URL,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        if response.result.value == nil {
                            fulfill()
                        }else {
                            reject(response.result.error!)
                        }
                    }
                    case .failure( _):
                    break
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

In case I put it on offline mode. It'll still execute the function and still fullfills() the promise. Even tho the network is offline. I think this is because it's checking if the encodingResult is succesful or not. NOt for the network call itself.

How am I able to check if the network call was successful or not? It's returning Void.

**Import notes:**

- Server returns nill if we receive 200 code which means that have uploaded the image.

Comment: I don't understand this. First, you don't fulfill or reject in the case of `.failure`. I would have thought that you want to `reject`. Second, if the response was `.success` but there was no `value`, you're fulfilling the promise, but if you did get a `value`, you are rejecting. That seems backwards.

Comment: The server returns "nil" if we have an 200 code. That's how it's setup. You are right that I need to add a reject in the .failure to but that doesn't change the situation.

Comment: How would you change the existing code? :) thanks for the tip btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use status codes to determine success or failure, you should add `validate`:

For example:

```
static func PUT(URL: String,
                data: Data,
                mimeType: String,
                headers: [String: String]?) -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in

        let URL = try! URLRequest(url: URL, method: .put, headers: headers)

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: mimeType)
        }, with: URL) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload
                    .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            fulfill()
                        case .failure(let error):
                            reject(error)
                        }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above assumes that upon successful response, you'll also get JSON response. You might want to do some additional checking of `value`.

If you're not returning JSON upon success, then just use `response`, not `responseJSON`:

```
static func PUT(URL: String,
                data: Data,
                mimeType: String,
                headers: [String: String]?) -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        let URL = try! URLRequest(url: URL, method: .put, headers: headers)

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: mimeType)
        }, with: URL) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload
                    .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)
                    .response { response in
                        if let error = response.error {
                            reject(error)
                        } else {
                            fulfill()
                        }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```